# Visual Studio with Qt VS Tools Throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" When Opening Qt Project File

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, qt

Hi I have a hopefully simple issue. When I try to open an existing Qt project file in Visual Studio 2019 by going to Extensions -> Qt VS Tools -> Open Qt Project File then selecting the project I get the error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". I have set the Qt version properly I think as in the screenshot. Any idea what might be wrong? There is a bin folder in the Qt install folder which contains qmake.exe and everything else but using that folder doesn't fix anything. One possibly important detail is that the Qt project points to files located on a mapped drive for a network share. Qt Creator opens the project just fine. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi, I am facing exactly the same problem, even if I am not working on a shared folder. Have you been able to find a solution?

Comment: Nope I abandoned all hope long ago. Maybe I'll give another go sometime down the line.

Answer (score 2):

finally I found the solution:

- open the project settings file yourproject.vcxprj with a test editor
- find the property group "globals"

> ```
> <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
>      <ProjectGuid>{AAAA-AAA-AAAAA-AAAA}</ProjectGuid>
>      <Keyword>QtVS_v302</Keyword>
> ```

- Change the Keyword property to "**QtVS_v302**" as above.
- Open the solution with Visual Studio and now QT Tools should work

In my case keywork was "**Qt4VSv1.0**" that probably was the setting of an old version of QT Tools that now is obsolete.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking... how in the world did you figure that out? lol

Comment: After many tries, I opened the .vcxprj file with text editor and I compared with a working project...

Comment: Good job I mightn't have figured that in a thousand years

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to post this as a comment rather than another answer, but the reputation system blocked me.

Mattia's answer solved the issue for me but I needed to use QtVS_v304 rather than QtVS_v302. It seems that Qt has created another project format.